# Find the value of x in the equation below

Tags: algebraic-equations

$\dfrac{3+x}{2022}+\dfrac{2+x}{2023}+\dfrac{1+x}{2024}+\dfrac{x}{2025}=-4$ $(S:x=-2025)$

Solving in the usual way we find the solution. I would like to know if there is a more practical way of solving this without using least common multiple.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think it is LCM in portugese

Comment: Solution is -2025 not -2005.

Comment: @WillJagy Why replace with x=t-2025? How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @AnneBauval  Yes

Comment: @OlderAmateur correct

Comment: Hint: Add 1 to each term on the LHS, and factor out $2025+x$. Show that the other term is non-zero, hence we require $2025+x = 0 $.

Comment: This equation has a unique solution, and there is an obvious one: the common solution of $\dfrac{3+x}{2022}=\dfrac{2+x}{2023}=\dfrac{1+x}{2024}=\dfrac{x}{2025}=-1.$

Comment: @WillJagy I don't just want to know the resolution but how to solve it. Just repeating what you say is not learning.

Comment: @CalvinLin perfect...thanks