# Does this method to simplify certain equations always work?

Tags: solution-verification

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812468/find-the-value-of-x-in-the-equation-below) Peta asks if there is a simple method to solve for x in
$$\dfrac{3+x}{2022}+\dfrac{2+x}{2023}+\dfrac{1+x}{2024}+\dfrac{x}{2025}=-4$$

There are some good replies in the comments of that question, but I was inspired to see if we can come up with a general purpose rule or method to quickly solve or simplify equations of this form.

Now I think we can say with certainty that if we have an equation of the form $$\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} + \frac{x+a_2}{x+b_2} + \frac{x+a_3}{y+b_3} = z$$ where $a_i,b_i,z \neq 0$, then if $\ \frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac z n$ (where n is the number of terms on the left) for each term on the left, it follows that

$$\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} = \frac{x+a_2}{x+b_2} = \frac{x+a_3}{y+b_3} = \frac{z}{n}$$. This works because we maintain the proportionality of the fractions. But what if one of the terms has $\frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac 0 0$? which is indeterminate? Peta's example hints that this can be handled. We can rewrite Peta's example as

$$\dfrac{x+3}{2025-3}+\dfrac{x+2}{2025-2}+\dfrac{x+1}{2025-1}+\dfrac{x+0}{2025-0}=-4$$ where n-1 of the terms on the left satisfies $\ \frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac z n$ but we have that problematic $\frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac 0 0$ for the last term on the LHS of the equation. I think we can safely say if n-1 terms on the left, satisfy the $\ \frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac z n$ condition, then the remaining term must satisfy the condition also, even if it has $\frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac 0 0$. This is where I am looking for assistance in a formal proof.

In summary, my conjecture is that if at least n-1 terms on the LHS of the equation satisfy $\frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac z n$ then all terms on the LHS are equal to each other. If this conjecture is true, this means given an equation like: $$\frac{x+560}{447+56}+\frac{x+20}{447+2}+\frac{x+120}{447+12}+\frac{x+30}{447+3}+\frac{x}{447}= 50$$ we can immediately simplify the equation to: $$5 \left(\dfrac{x}{447}\right) = 50$$ and conclude $x = \frac{50*447}{5} = 4470$.

In fact we can just "eyeball" the equation and deduce $x = y z/n = 4470$.

This should also work when there are only two terms on the LHS and only one of the terms has $\frac{a_i}{b_i} \neq \frac 0 0$, for example: $$\frac{x+30}{8+3}+\frac{x+0}{8+0}= 20$$ $$2 \left( \frac{x}{8} \right) = 20$$ $$x= 80$$

Is this already a well known method or is my conjecture false?

Taking Calvin Lin's counter example into account, I think I need to add the condition that y should be known non zero constant value.

As pointed out by David K, I made an error in extending the method to solve cases where the terms are not equal such as this one posed by Calvin Lin:

$\frac{ x+26}{10} + \frac{x+22}{11} + \frac{x}{12} + \frac{x-16}{13} = -10$.

That case needs more work.

Comment: 1/ If you have a 0/0, then that $x$ is not a solution to the problem. 2/ The "general solution" is to clear denominators and factorize the polynomial. However, this can be tough to do. The important part is finding a factor, as opposed to "assume they are of the form z/n" 3/ My hint of "Add 1 to each term to factorize out $2025+x$" essentially determines a factor of the expansion, without having to do the expansion. This can be adapted in various ways. $\quad$ EG try to solve $\frac{ x+26}{10} + \frac{x+22}{11} + \frac{x}{12} + \frac{x-16}{13} = -10$.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Could you give a worked example in your answer, of how you would solve your example by adding 1 to each term on the LHS?

Comment: To my clear, my crux is to "factor out common term", as opposed to "add 1 to each term". In the case of the example, if you add 1, 2, 3, 4 to the terms, you can factor out $ x + 36$.

Comment: The thing that bothers me about this is the use of the term "simplifies". Normally when someone simplifies an equation, it's because the simplification will make the equation easier to use, for example to find the value of an unknown or to compute the value of a function. But you don't have any reason to need to simplify the equation, because you've already discovered the solution $x = yz/n$. But all you can do with this is to prove that $x=yz/n$ is **a** solution; you have not proved that it is **the** unique solution (and indeed it might not be).

Comment: @CalvinLin I think your second term in the "EG" should be $\frac{x+14}{11}$. KDP: your method fails for the example as written (with $22$ instead of $14$); the solution to that equation is $x = -114708/3013$.

Comment: @DavidK Yes. The idea is to factor out $ (x+36)$.

Comment: @KDP Note the typo in my stated example. Also, your solution is invalid, as the assumption that each of the terms have the same value is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer to the title question is, "No, not **always**."
But when the equation is written as stated in the question,
it is possible to conclude that $x = yz/n$ is a solution
without needing to rewrite the equation in a "simplified" form.
This is simple to show even in the case where $a_k = b_k = 0$ in one or more terms.

---

Further details:

You don't need to divide by zero.
You can simply require that $a_k = \dfrac zn b_k$
for $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, which is still defined on both sides and true when $a_k$ and $b_k$ are both zero.

What **will** be a problem is if $b_k = -y$ for some $b_k$, because then you actually do have a division by zero. Of course, when the problem is given with explicit numbers (like the problem from the other question), the division by zero will be quite obvious.

Note that
\begin{multline}
\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} + \frac{x+a_2}{y+b_2} + \cdots + \frac{x+a_n}{y+b_n} = \\
\left(\frac{1}{y+b_1} + \frac{1}{y+b_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{y+b_n}\right) x
+ \left(\frac{a_1}{y+b_1} + \frac{a_2}{y+b_2} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{y+b_n}\right),
\end{multline}
so when we set this quantity equal to $z$ we have an equation of the form
$mx + b = z$, which has exactly one solution if $m\neq 0$ and has either no solution or infinitely many solutions if $m = 0$.

If $m = 0$ we cannot conclude that $\dfrac xy = \dfrac zn$.
For example, consider

$$
\frac{x+1}{1+1} + \frac{x-3}{1-3} = 2.
$$

This satisfies the condition that $a_k = \dfrac zn b_k$
for $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$,
and every real $x$ is a solution.

If $y + b_k$ has the same sign for every $k$ then $m \neq 0$, but that is not a necessary condition. If $m = 0$ then it is sufficient to make any change in exactly one of the $a_k$ values in order to ensure that $m \neq 0$.

If you want a formal proof, I think your best bet is first to prove that each term of the sum is equal to $\frac zn$ when $x = \frac zn y$, essentially as you did already.
Then add up the $n$ equal terms.
But it must be all $n$ terms, not just $n - 1$ terms.

Try something like this:

If $a_k = \frac zn b_k$ and $x = \frac zn y$,
then
$$ x + a_k = \frac zn y + \frac zn b_k = \frac zn (y + b_k). $$

Provided that $y + b_k \neq 0$, we can divide each side by $y + b_k$
to show that
$$
\frac{x + a_k}{y + b_k} = \frac zn.
$$

---

I think now I really must emphasize that
$$
n\left(\frac xy\right) = z
$$
is **not** a generally valid simplification of the equation
$$
\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} + \frac{x+a_2}{y+b_2} +  \cdots \frac{x+a_n}{y+b_n} = z.
$$
These two equations are equivalent (have the same solutions for $x$)
only under the additional condition that
$$
\frac{1}{y+b_1} + \frac{1}{y+b_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{y+b_n} \neq 0. \tag{C}
$$

There is no valid "simplification" from one equation to the other unless you include this condition as a requirement for the simplification.

To solve the problem in general, it is sufficient to recognize that
$x = \frac zn y$ is a solution and then to check whether there are any other solutions. For the check for other solutions, you have two options:

a) Verify Inequality (C). This can be easy to do; for example, if all denominators are positive, you have a unique solution.

b) Check just one other value of $x$. You can check $x = 0$ or $x = -a_1$ or any value of $x$ you find convenient. If the equation is still true, it's true for all $x$; otherwise, $x = \frac zn y$ is the unique solution.

---

There are, of course, innumerable other ways of invalidating the solution method by making minor adjustments to the problem, such as combining multiple terms into one or multiplying $x$ by some coefficient other than $1$ in one of the terms. But every one of those creates an equation that is **not** in the form
$$
\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} + \frac{x+a_2}{y+b_2} +  \cdots + \frac{x+a_n}{y+b_n} = z
\tag{P}
$$
where there are exactly $n$ terms on the left-hand side.
So we can lump all of these exceptions into one general exception:
"if the equation is not in the exact form of Equation (P)."

There are also many ways to modify the solution so that some of these exceptions are no longer exceptions. For example,
let $C = \sum_1^n c_k$ where each $c_k$ is a known fixed value and $C \neq 0$,
let $a_k = \dfrac{c_k z}{C} b_k$ for $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$
where $a_k$ and $b_k$ are known fixed values, let $y$ and $z$ be known fixed values, let $y + b_k \neq 0$ for $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, and let
$$
\frac{c_1 x + a_1}{y + b_1} + \frac{c_2 x + a_2}{y + b_2} + \cdots
 + \frac{c_n x + a_n}{y + b_n} = z. \tag{Q}
$$
Then if $x = \dfrac{z}{C} y$ for $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$,
we find that for each $k$,
$$
c_k x + a_k = c_k \frac zC y + \frac{c_k z}C b_k = c_k \frac zC (y + b_k)
$$
and dividing by $y + b_k$ on each side, we find that
$$
\frac{c_k x + a_k}{y + b_k} = c_k \frac zC.
$$
Then the left-hand side of Equation (Q) is
$$
\sum_1^n \frac{c_k x + a_k}{y + b_k}
= \sum_1^n c_k \frac zC = \frac zC \sum_1^n c_k = \frac zC C = z,
$$
and therefore $x = \dfrac{z}{C} y$ is a solution of Equation (Q).
Equation (P) is just Equation (Q) with $c_k = 1$ for every $k$.

Now further suppose that we replace the condition $y + b_k \neq 0$ with the condition $d_k y + b_k \neq 0$ for $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$,
where each $d_k$ is a known fixed quantity. Let
$$
\frac{c_1 d_1 x + a_1}{d_1 y + b_1} + \frac{c_2 d_2 x + a_2}{d_2 y + b_2}
 + \cdots + \frac{c_n d_n x + a_n}{d_n y + b_n} = z. \tag{R}
$$
Through methods similar to the ones before, we can show that
if $x = \dfrac{z}{C} y$ then
$$
\frac{c_k d_k x + a_k}{d_k y + b_k} = c_k \frac zC
$$
and therefore $x = \dfrac{z}{C} y$ is a solution of Equation (R).

By this point, however, it may be getting difficult to recognize whether an
equation actually is in the form (R) when each of the quantities
$c_k d_k$ and $d_k y + b_k$ has been written as a single explicit number
such as $30$ or $2025$.
At some point, as we generalize the method, I think we will reach a point where the generalization is no longer useful or interesting.

Comment: Having carefully checked the arguments in your answer, I have decided to upvote your answer and declare your answer as the correct one, for showing the exceptions to the rule and helpfully showing how to improve the rule to allow for and detect those exceptions. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I have decided to leave the question open because I have thought of another exception. Imagine there are 5 terms on the LHS, and we add 4 of those terms together, it will appear as if n=2 which will give incorrect solutions. We could say n is the sum of the coefficients of x instead of the number of terms. Worse still, we could replace the 4x in the combined term with x + numeric value of 3x so the sum of coefficients appears to be 2. How do we allow for that?

Comment: If you add four of the terms in problem of this kind, you don't get $4x+\text{constant}$ in the numerator unless all the denominators are equal. If you further alter the equation so that this term has only $x+\text{constant}'$ in the numerator by taking the intended solution value of $x$, multiplying by $3$, and adding it to the constant, then you're back to the original form of the equation except that now $a_k \neq \frac zn b_k$ and you should know not to say that $\frac zn y$ (where $n$ is now $2$) is a solution.

Comment: I don't think anything in my last comment constitutes an "exception" to the method; rather, it constitutes a different problem statement that the method explicitly excludes already. But I've added some valid extensions of the method to cases where $x$ can have a coefficient other than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have described, if $\frac{a_i}{b_i} = \frac{z}{n}$ for all $i$, then a solution to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x+a_i}{y+b_i} = z$ is simply $x = \frac{z}{n} \cdot y$
as setting $\frac{x+a_i}{y+b_i} = \frac{z}{n}$ for every $i$ is equivalent to setting $x = \frac{z}{n} \cdot y$.

The reason the problem you describe can be solved even though $a_4/b_4 = 0/0$ is because a substition of $x = t+1$ transforms the problem into

$$ \dfrac{t+4}{2026-4}+\dfrac{t+3}{2026-3}+\dfrac{t+2}{2026-2}+\dfrac{t+1}{2026-1}=-4, $$ which gives (by your method) $t = -\frac{4}{4} \cdot 2026 $, so $x = -2025$.

You observation that the $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0/0$ still allows this method to work is therefore valid, when:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x+a_i}{y+b_i} = z$, when subsituted with
$x = t + k$ so $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{t+ (k+a_i)}{(y-uk)+(uk+b_i)}$ preserves the ratios (it can be shown that by selecting $u = \frac{b_i}{a_i}$ that is sufficient to keep the ratios constant). In all of these cases the substitution $x = t+k$ avoids the 0/0 cases and even more, the solution of the equation is the same as if you ignore the $0/0$ cases as is your conjecture (the anwser will still be $x = \frac{z}{n} \cdot y$ regardless of the substitution).

Comment: +1 for the substitute t = x+1 method to eliminate the a/b=0/0 doubt. Nice work.

Comment: i have generalized it further in the edit, which I think proves your conjecture fully.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a solution. More a critique of the initial writeup)

As a counterexample,

$$\frac{ x}{x} + \frac{ x+1}{x+1} + \frac{x+2}{x+2} = 3$$

has solutions of $ x \in \mathbb{R} - \{0, 1, 2 \}$.

Even though substituting in $ x = 0 $ results in $ \frac{x+1}{x+1} = 1, \frac{x+2}{x+2} = 1$, the other term is not 1, and hence $x=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: Using the method in the OP, your equation resolves to $3\left(\frac x x \right) = 3$ which gives x=x which has infinite solutions or is indeterminate. It seems the method fails when x=y. Is there any way to allow for that?

Comment: @KDP As I said, it has solutions of $ x \in \mathbb{R} - \{0, 1, 2 \}$. You have to ensure that the denominator is non-zero (which could be a condition put in place to trip people up, which I've done before).

Comment: The question has no $x$ in the denominator of any term. It's just a linear equation in $x$ arranged in a peculiar way.

Comment: @DavidK I'm referring to a more general case. $\quad$ To be clear, I advocate for "finding a factor" as opposed to this idea.

Comment: Ah, so if you apply the proposed method of "simplification" to your example, you get $3\left(\frac xx\right)=3$, which is "almost" equivalent to the original equation, but differs from the original equation at $x\in\{1,2\}$. In my answer, I have a further critique of the "simplification" in the case where all named quantities except $x$ are known fixed values.